# Ocultar botones Atras, Home, Aplicaciones en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo problemas para poder implementar de manera correcta como ocultar los botones que están ubicandos en la parte inferior/footer de móvil. Esos 3 botones de Atrás, Home, Aplicaciones.

Estoy implementando este código y funciona correctamente, oculta la barra de navegación TOP y la del Footer.

Pero el problema es cuando pincho en mi EditText, que me aparece el Teclado Virtual. Una vez acabado lo que se quiera escribir, los 3 botones de Atrás, Home, Aplicaciones. Están de vuelta visibles. ¿Que me falta por implementar?, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: ¿La barra superior también se muestra nuevamente?

Answer (score 0):

Para algunas versiones de sistema operativo tal vez no funcione el código que realizas, incluso tendrás comportamientos como el que describes, por lo tanto, considero que la mejor opción es crear un estilo y agregarlo en tu archivo `styles.xml` :

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

y este estilo definirlo a tu `Activity` para que siempre estén "escondidos" los botones y la barra de estatus.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen">
```